# Centos 7 preserve the /etc/group- permission

Tags: centos

During my server build I am setting /etc/group-file permission to  mode: 0600. After while this permission changes to 644.  not sure how its changing.

What is the based way to keep this file permission same all the time?

Thanks
SR

Comment: What is the problem that you're trying to solve by resetting the permissions on /etc/group? Seems a sure-fire way to break use group permissions.

Comment: I want to Hardening  the server.

Comment: Why do you think changing perms on /etc/group will achieve any hardening? Security through obscurity argument perhaps? Will you be changing /etc/passwd for the same reasons? No, I don't know what is changing the perms. Only idea I have a a weird SELinux policy - I assume the first this you did to harden the system to turn on SELinux in enforcing mode.

Comment: Its based on CIS standard we have to configure the server.  you can see some more details on this page. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3190922

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about `/etc/group-` that is a back up of the `/etc/group` file. The permission are probably changing whenever a new backup is generated, like after creating a user or something like that. The default `umask` value is usually 022 (removes write from group and world) which would result in 644 for new files.

Changing the default `umask` in `/etc/profile` is not a good idea. You might want to look at the answer to this post [serverfault.com/questions/361665/inherit-or-set-permissions-for-all-new-files-under-a-specific-path](https://serverfault.com/questions/361665/inherit-or-set-permissions-for-all-new-files-under-a-specific-path).

Comment: you right, we don't want to change umask, setting setuid bit also not good idea. may be for now I will add cron job to fix this permission issue.